# Docker and Vagrant connection

Tags: curl, networking, docker, vagrant, docker-compose

I have 2 apps set locally. One (app_v) is running on vagrant, and I can access it on browser with http://192.168.50.5:3000/.

Second (app_d) is running on docker-compose, and I can access it on browser with
http://192.168.50.6:3000/.

The problem is, they **don't seem to fully see each other**. I ssh into my vagrant machine of app_v. I run:

```
 ping on 192.168.50.6
```

and it works. But with curl:

```
curl http://192.168.50.6:3000/
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

**What's important:** error shows up after like 30 seconds. If I change port to something wrong, like 9999, error shows up **immediately**.

Other points:

- If I ssh into docker app_d result is the same for ping 192.168.50.5 and curl http://192.168.50.5:3000/
- If I run same commands from outside of app_v or app_d, both ping and curl **works** (and this is why browser works too).
- Both apps run on centos67, they are both rails apps

Vagrantfile network part of app_v:

```
  config.vm.network 'public_network', ip: '192.168.50.5'
  config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 3000, host: 8080
  config.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 5432, host: 5434
```

Docker compose setup of app_d:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    build: docker/database
    container_name: postgres
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.50.10
    ports:
      - "5436:5432"

  app:
    build: .
    container_name: app_d
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.50.6
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8086:3000"
      - "2226:22"
    links:
      - db

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.50.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.50.1
```

Do You have any ideas why I cannot connect between them?

**EDIT**
I've narrowed it down a bit. It works as expected if I use:

```
    config:
    - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
      ip_range: 172.28.5.0/24
```

And 172.20.128.3 as IP. I can access then server through  172.20.128.3:3000 via curl.
So what's wrong with that particular IP or subnet?